# PowerShell - Invalid Characters in Save Path

Tags: mysql, charts, powershell-5.0, invalid-characters

I'm sure there are numerous things wrong with this script - but right now the only thing that's throwing any kind of error is the SaveImage part.  So, script will pull results from MySql Queries, and use that information to make charts.  Except it won't save the charts.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization")
$scriptPath = "C:\Users\Public\reports\img"

Connect-MySqlServer -ComputerName [SERVER] -Port 3306 -Database [DB] -Credential (Get-Credential)

$locations = Invoke-MySqlQuery "[...]"

ForEach ($location in $locations) {
    $loc = $location.locationID
    $dataSource = Invoke-MySqlQuery "[...]"
    $c = (Invoke-MySqlQuery "[...]").name | Out-String
    $s = (Invoke-MySqlQuery "[...]").name | Out-String

    $chart1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
    $chart1.Width = 600
    $chart1.Height = 400
    $chart1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White

    [void]$chart1.Titles.Add("Test Chart")
    $chart1.Titles[0].Font = "Segoe UI,13pt"
    $chart1.Titles[0].Alignment = "topLeft"

    $chartArea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
    $chartArea.Name = "ChartArea1"
    $chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Y Axis"
    $chartArea.AxisX.Title = "X Axis"
    $chartArea.AxisY.Interval = 5
    $chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 1
    $chartArea.AxisY.MaximumAutoSize = $false
    $chartArea.AxisX.MaximumAutoSize = $false
    $chartArea.AxisY.Maximum = 80
    $chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = 30
    $chart1.ChartAreas.Add($chartArea)

    $legend = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend
    $legend.Name = "Legend1"
    $chart1.Legends.Add($legend)

    [void]$chart1.Series.Add("U")
    $chart1.Series["U"].ChartType = "Line"
    $chart1.Series["U"].BorderWidth = 3
    $chart1.Series["U"].IsVisibleInLegend = $True
    $chart1.Series["U"].ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
    $chart1.Series["U"].Legend = "Legend1"
    $chart1.Series["U"].Color = "#7CB5EC"
    ForEach ($point in $dataSource) {$chart1.Series["U"].Points.addxy($($point.t),[math]::Round(($point.u) / 1024),2))}

    [void]$chart1.Series.Add("D")
    $chart1.Series["D"].ChartType = "Line"
    $chart1.Series["D"].BorderWidth = 3
    $chart1.Series["D"].IsVisibleInLegend = $True
    $chart1.Series["D"].ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
    $chart1.Series["D"].Legend = "Legend1"
    $chart1.Series["D"].Color = "#FFA500"
    ForEach ($point in $dataSource) {$chart1.Series["D"].Points.addxy($($point.t),[math]::Round(($($point.d) / 1024),2))}

    $filename = $scriptPath + "\" + ($c).replace(" ","") + "_" + ($s).replace(" ","") + ".png"

    $filename = ($filename).replace("`n","")

    $chart1.SaveImage("$filename","png")
}
```

This returns:

```
Exception calling "SaveImage" with "2" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."
At line:62 char:1
+ $chart1.SaveImage("$filename","png")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the `Out-String` used with the `$c` and `$s` Queries, but when I don't do that, I get other issues.  And `$filename` without the `.replace` returns:

```
C:\Users\Public\reports\img\$c
_$s
.png
```

So, I used the following to check `$filename` for Invalid Characters:

```
$pattern = "[{0}]" -f ([Regex]::Escape([String][System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join '' ))
$filename -match $pattern
$matches
```

Which returns:

```
True
Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              :
```

When i `cd` to the directory, and attempt to save the file as `$filename` without `$scriptPath`, to get rid of the ':' after the Drive Letter, I get the following `$matches`:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              ...
```

So, I'm completely at a loss.  If anyone has any insight, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: can you `echo @$filename@`

Comment: Yeah, it returns correct: `C:\Users\Public\reports\img\$c_$s.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set variable with file name, clean it and use

```
$fn = ($c).replace(" ","") + "_" + ($s).replace(" ","") + ".png"
$fp = $scriptPath + "\" + ($f -replace ("[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join '')))
$chart1.SaveImage($fp,"png")
```